# Disable a Test Case if another Test Case has not run in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, testing, microsoft-test-manager

I have a question about Microsoft Test Manager:

Lets say I have two Test Cases, Test A and Test B.
Is it possible to disable Test B from running if Test A hasn't runned yet?

Edit: I'm talking about manual test cases!

Thanks!

Comment: Are these automated test cases? Or are you wanting to prevent someone from running a manual test case unless a different manual test case has been ran?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent someone from running a manual test case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you ask.

Comment: Okay, thanks for conforming this. I've spend a long time on searching this, but didn't found it!